# Translating a hash in a simple form Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, internationalization

I would like to translate a hash in a simple form in Ruby on Rails. On my product show page, I let the customer choose between two product options which have different prices. Ordering a bracelet with a gift bag (12.95€) and without a giftbag (11,95€).

The following code in the product show works fine in the sense that it passes the right price to the cart_item:

`<%= f.input :pack_size, collection: Product::BRACELET_OPTIONS.keys.map { |x| x.to_s }, label: false, prompt: false %>`

This is the code in the product.rb:

```
BRACELET_OPTIONS = {
    "With gift bag - 12.95€": 12.95,
    "Without gift bag - 11.95€": 11.95
   }
```

My problem is that I am trying to translate the phrases (keys)'with gift bag' and 'without gift bag'. I don't know how to adjust the code in the product show accordingly.

I would appreciate any help with this.

Comment: Have you tried Rails i18n: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html?

Comment: Yes I did and I manage to translate other product options with this code: <%= f.input :colour, collection: [:white, :pink, :light_blue], prompt: t('forms.choosepompomcolour'), label: false, required: true%> and then putting the translation into .yml file. However these other options are not a hash

Comment: What prevents you from doing?

`BRACELET_OPTIONS = { t('forms.with...'): 12.95, t('forms.without...'): 11.95 }`

Comment: if I do that, it throws an error undefined method 't'

Comment: if i use the following code in the product show, the translation works fine but then the value is not passed to the cart_item:  <%= f.input :pack_size, collection: Product::BRACELET_OPTIONS.map {|key, value| t("#{key}", price: value, locale: params[:locale])}, prompt: false %>.  So I am able to translate it or to pass the value, but i want both!

Comment: To follow up on @BTL s comment, you need the `I18n.t` unless you alias it in a base controller or something

Comment: omg yes if I change to I18n.t, it works!!! thank you so much @Int'l Man Of Coding Mystery

Comment: and thank you @BTL, this is amazing! :)

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery Using `I18n.t` to define a constant in the model  is pretty stinky. If the model is not reloaded per request you can end up with the wrong translations.

Comment: @max, do you have a better idea?

Comment: I do have the problem that it doesn't change the translation when I use the language toggle. I was thinking that I might need to add `locale: params[:locale]` to this code in the product show `<%= f.input :pack_size, collection: Product::BRACELET_OPTIONS.keys.map { |x| x.to_s }, label: false, prompt: false %>` but I don't know where to put it exactly (sorry, I am a still a beginner)

Comment: @Alex You don't have to alias it, you can use `I18n.t("...")` in all the places you need a translation. I've just seen it done in other apps

Comment: @Int'lManOfCodingMystery, it does work but when i use the language toggle on my website, it doesn't change to the other language. Any idea how i can fix that? I was thinking of adding `locale: params[:locale]`to the code in the product show: `<%= f.input :pack_size, collection: Product::BRACELET_OPTIONS.keys.map { |x| x.to_s }, label: false, prompt: false %> `

Comment: i'm not too familiar with changing the locals like that. I was just commenting on why just using the `t` wasn't working. I'm sorry :(